# Loading an image from a C source file, exported from GIMP

Tags: c, visual-c++, textures, gimp

I'm trying to load an openGL texture for a game. The texture is an image that has been exported as a `.C source file` from GIMP. When I `#include` this file in my project (using Visual C++ 2010 Ultimate), I get a compiler error saying `fatal error C1091: compiler limit: string exceeds 65535 bytes in length`

Is there ***any*** workaround ?

The reason I wanted to export the image as a **C header file** was so that the program compiles with the image, and I dont have to provide `raw` image files along with the executable.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <glfw.h>
#include "X.c"

#define X 1
#define O 2

#pragma comment(lib, "glfw.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")

using namespace std;

float render();
void stepGame(float);
void keyboard(int, int);

int main(int argv, int *argc[])
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwOpenWindow(480, 480, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, GLFW_WINDOW);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(keyboard);
    glfwSetWindowTitle("Tic Tac Toe!");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    float dT;

    while(glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED) > 0)
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        dT = render();
        stepGame(dT);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Image file:
[X.c](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35856163/X.c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution. Export the image as a raw data file, then use [bin2hex](http://www.chami.com/tips/delphi/052098d.html) to convert it to a C/C++ array. This will work fine because instead of a huge string this script generates a char array. Here is an example:

```
$ bin2hex.pl
bin2hex.pl by Chami.com

usage:
  perl bin2hex.pl <binary file> <language id>

  <binary file> : path to the binary file
  <language id> : 0 = Perl, 1 = C/C++/Java, 2 = Pascal/Delphi

$ bin2hex.pl x.bin 1

/* begin binary data: */
char bin_data[] = /* 112 */
{0x23,0x69,0x6E,0x63,0x6C,0x75,0x64,0x65,0x20,0x3C,0x73,0x74,0x64,0x69,0x6F
,0x2E,0x68,0x3E,0x0A,0x23,0x69,0x6E,0x63,0x6C,0x75,0x64,0x65,0x20,0x3C,0x74
,0x69,0x6D,0x65,0x2E,0x68,0x3E,0x0A,0x0A,0x69,0x6E,0x74,0x20,0x6D,0x61,0x69
,0x6E,0x28,0x69,0x6E,0x74,0x20,0x61,0x72,0x67,0x63,0x2C,0x20,0x63,0x68,0x61
,0x72,0x2A,0x20,0x61,0x72,0x67,0x76,0x5B,0x5D,0x29,0x0A,0x7B,0x0A,0x20,0x20
,0x20,0x20,0x70,0x72,0x69,0x6E,0x74,0x66,0x28,0x22,0x25,0x64,0x5C,0x6E,0x22
,0x2C,0x20,0x73,0x69,0x7A,0x65,0x6F,0x66,0x28,0x74,0x69,0x6D,0x65,0x5F,0x74
,0x29,0x29,0x3B,0x0A,0x7D,0x0A,0x0A};
/* end binary data. size = 112 bytes */
```

Comment: This will work, but it's a PERL script. Isn't there a binary or something that I can use ?

Comment: I downloaded PERL, and converted to binary, but now OpenGl wont load the texture.

Comment: You need to export your image as raw. Any other format won't work.

Answer (score 3):

I made a better [gimp plug-in](http://karibe.co.ke/2015/06/writing-a-gimp-based-lcd-icon-designer/) in python to export image data as C code. Feel free to use it or make it better for custom use. The scripts are available on a [github repository](https://github.com/Muriukidavid/gimp-plugins.git). Hope that helps.

Comment: I upvoted this, but in reality the documentation for this GIMP plugin (while a start in the right direction) is not so good for me right now. E.g., how do we use the macro *_RUN_LENGTH_DECODE(...) generated by this utility?

Comment: @mds I have no idea what you are talking about. What utility? I presented a plugin which when installed in Gimp produces C code with an array of pixel data of the form
    `RGB image[300]={
    {0,0,0},{0,0,0}...};`

no macro. Kindly check the first link in the answer.